# <Content> in NativeBase 3?

Tags: react-native, native-base

Is there an element in NativeBase3 that replaces the Content element in NativeBase2? Essentially a keyboard aware scrolling view.

I was also wondering if there is an easy way to un-focus an Input by tapping off of it (I think the Content element solved this as well).

Thanks!